# Can a server in any case request a client for any service?

Tags: reporting-services, client, client-server

Can a server in any case request a client for any service?

Answer (score 0):

How can a server request a client for a service? Its a client that will request the server for a service.

Well what exactly is your question? Can you add more details?

Comment: Unless we're talking about X11, in which case client means server and server means client...

Answer (score 0):

If you are taking in respect of web application then no. Server will always provide response for any request made by the client.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is install some type of plug in or active x object on the client that runs on the client, and sends information back to the server.  However, there are security concerns there.  In any case, it is not the server requesting anything, it is the client that runs an application and then connects to the server again.

If you can be more clear about what you need to accomplish I think you will get a clearer answer.